# Intellij Console output

Tags: intellij-idea, console

Here is an output to a simple piece of code:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-
javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 
CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=63996:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 
CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath 
/Users/Ice/IdeaProjects/HelloWorld/out/production/HelloWorld hello

Dice roller, how many dice?
2
Dice number =: 2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How do i remove the annoying path from the begining of the console output, i have a very hard time searching for an answer to this question as i do not know the keywords to search for.

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot disable printing of the command line however you can fold it as follows:

- Right click on that line in the console
- Choose `Fold Lines Like This`
- Hit `OK` (optionally, you can customise the pattern to, for example, fold all lines that start with: "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines")

Folded lines still appear in the console but they do not dominate the console output or obscure output which is more important to you i.e. folding is a way to improve the signal:noise ratio.

If folding is helpful to you then you might want to consider using [Grep Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console) (see @Meo's comment) because it comes with some built in fold configurations (aswell as allowing you to define your own) and its log file highlighting and filtering features can be used to greatly improve the signal:noise ratio.